# Java: try-catch-resources with return and throw new statements

Tags: java, try-catch, try-catch-finally

This is my cose:

```java
private ResultSetType makeRequest() {
    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = this.sendRequest(request)) {
        String responseBody = IOUtils.toString(
            response.getEntity().getContent(),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8
        );
            
        if (HttpStatus.SC_OK == response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()) {
            // do something;
            return ...
        } else {
            throw new LoaderSystemFault(LoaderConstants.ErrorCodes.ERR_002, "Communication error with Servei Territorial (status-code: {0} / request: {1} / response: {2})", response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), request, responseBody);
        }
    } catch (IOException | JAXBException e) {
        throw new LoaderSystemFault(LoaderConstants.ErrorCodes.ERR_002, "Communication error with Servei Territorial (status-code: {0} / request: {1} / response: {2})", response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), request, responseBody);
    }
}
```

My goal is to close `CloseableHttpResponse`.

Several questions here:

- What about `return` statement inside `try-catch-resources`?
- What about `throw new`  statements?

It's not clear to me if `CloseableHttpResponse` will be closed regardless of whether `return` or `thow new` statements are reached.

How could I refactor above code?

Any ideas?

Comment: It will be closed via all possible paths. No need to change your code.

Comment: What are you trying to ask with "What about return statement inside try-catch-resources?" Isn't that already answered by "It's clear to me if CloseableHttpResponse will be closed regardless of whether return or thow new statements are reached."?

Comment: "What about X?" is not a clear question. What about those things is your question?

Comment: @Sweeper miswritting, I meant "It's NOT clear to me". Solved.

Comment: Well it doesn't help much when you ask the oppossite of what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.2), a try-with-resources like the one you have there is first translated to:

```
try {
    try (CloseableHttpResponse response = this.sendRequest(request)) {
        String responseBody = IOUtils.toString(
            response.getEntity().getContent(),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8
        );
            
        if (HttpStatus.SC_OK == response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()) {
            // do something;
            return ...
        } else {
            throw new LoaderSystemFault(LoaderConstants.ErrorCodes.ERR_002, "Communication error with Servei Territorial (status-code: {0} / request: {1} / response: {2})", response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), request, responseBody);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException | JAXBException e) {
    throw new LoaderSystemFault(LoaderConstants.ErrorCodes.ERR_002, "Communication error with Servei Territorial (status-code: {0} / request: {1} / response: {2})", response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), request, responseBody);
}
```

The inner try-with-with resources is now a basic try-with-resources statement, and is translated like this:

```
{
    final CloseableHttpResponse response = this.sendRequest(request);
    Throwable #primaryExc = null;

    try {
        // everything in your try block
    } catch (Throwable #t) {
        #primaryExc = #t;
        throw #t;
    } finally {
        if (response != null) {
            if (#primaryExc != null) {
                try {
                    response.close();
                } catch (Throwable #suppressedExc) {
                    #primaryExc.addSuppressed(#suppressedExc);
                }
            } else {
                response.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The important thing to note is that the block in the original try-with-resources gets translated to the `try` block of the try-catch-finally, and the closing of the resource is done in the `finally` block.

This means that the semantics of normal try-catch-finally statements apply here - if the `try` block completes abruptly (i.e. returns or throws) or if it completes normally, the `finally` block *will* get executed. See [§14.20.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2) for the exact details. You'll see that `finally` is executed in every case mentioned in the spec.

So in conclusion, your resource will be closed even if `return` or `throw` is reached.